# Error in Bitmap create function for devices greater than API 22

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-6.0-marshmallow

The below function does not work for devices greater than API 22.

```
 Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(2160, 16777214, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

**Error Log:**

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.setHasAlpha(boolean)' on a null object reference
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:835)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at com.controller.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:51)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
02-10 11:01:37.478 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
02-10 11:01:37.479 6473-6473/com.mazzmedia.daitem1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realize you are asking for a 144 Gigabyte sized Bitmap with your request of 2160 pixels high, 16777214 pixels wide, and having each pixel take up 4 bytes as defined by `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

The math makes that to be 2160 x 16777214 x 4 which equals 144955128960 bytes. I'm unclear as to which device you expect this to work on.

Solution: Don't create such a large bitmap.